# Alternative to Rownum / Get the last inserts on Oracle Database

Tags: php, oracle

I want to display the latest inserts on my oracle Database, what I was trying to do is save the rownum of the last row, then do my insert and finally get the inserts `"using select * from table where rownum >".$lastrow;`

Now that I understood how rownum works, I get that my query will not work.
Is there any alternative (in Oracle or PHP)?
My actual code is :

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX (ROWNUM) from TABLE";
$query2 = $connexion -> prepare($sql);
$query2 -> execute();
$result = $query2 -> fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$arr = array_values($result[0]);
$lastrow = $arr[0];

//Insertion

for ($i=1;$i<count($puts);$i++){
    $line=explode(';',$puts[$i]);
    $connexion->exec("INSERT INTO TABLE (Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5) SELECT '".$line[0]."',$line[1],'".$line[2]."','".$line[3]."','".$line[4]."'FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from TABLE where Col2= '$line[2]')");
    $line=array();
}

//last inserts :

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM TABLE where ROWNUM >".$lastrow;
$query3 = $connexion -> prepare($sql2);
$query3 -> execute();
```

Comment: It looks like you're using PDO so you should be able to use, http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php.

Comment: For such requirements, ideally you should have a TIMESTAMP column. Every new insert will have a timestamp and you could easily fetch the latest inserts by sorting the rows based on the timestamp..

Comment: ordering of rows isn't guranteed, just because it looks like they're ordered, doesn't mean they are - unless you do an ORDER BY. if an order is necessary, listen to @LalitKumarB's advice

Comment: @LalitKumarB the use of a Timestamp would be great..but my table does not contain a Timestamp table and I cannot create one :/ Is there any other way ?

Comment: `ROWNUM` is a pseudocolumn which is generated when you run the query, it has nothing to do with the order of inserting.

Comment: Probably the best way is to use a TIMESTAMP as per Lalit; another way is to use an ID based on a sequence with the ORDERED option (it might not perform well in a RAC system though).

Comment: Just to be clear: unless the *data itself* gives you the information you need, there is no hidden "metadata" you can use to reliably reconstruct the order in which rows were inserted. Note that even the concept of "order of insertion" is somewhat meaningless in a relational database - what if an INSERT statement inserts more than one row? There is no meaningful answer to that question.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp you're right(+1). I was hoping there was some Oracle metadata that can help me (too bad the developer that created the database in the first place did not think of **insertedAt** and **updatedAt** columns...whice would have made the manipulation of the data more simple)... As for the answer to this question, It will be some php workaround (working on it).